# Django: Best way to retrieve object

Tags: django, django-queryset

Lets assume that I have a class `Person` with a field `email`. I want to get a single record based on queryset and assign it to variable `person`. Sadly I cannot do

```
person = Person.objects.filter(email="xxx@xxx.xxx")[0]
```

because I might get an exception. So:

**Scenario 1**: Include the above code in a try-except.

**Scenario 2** (which I'm currently using):

```
person_arr = Person.objects.filter(email="xxx@xxx.xxx")
if person_arr.exists():
    person = person_arr[0]
    ....
```

**Scenario 3**

```
for person in Person.objects.filter(email="xxx@xxx.xxx"):
    ....
```

**Scenario 4**: You suggest something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the two correct way in my opinion:

1. Try-except solution (your Scenario1 ):

   ```
   try:
       person = Person.objects.get(email="xxx@xxx.xxx")
   except Person.DoesNotExist:
       person= None
   ```
2. Django 1.6+ solution using [first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#first) (recommended):

   ```
   person = Person.objects.filter(email="xxx@xxx.xxx").first()
   ```

This is from the documentation:

> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is
>   no matching object. If the QuerySet has no ordering defined, then the
>   queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key.

This solution will allow you to do whatever you want if the object does not exist.

Note that this will work only if no emails are duplicated which makes total sense in this case.

Comment: I like the `first` solution. However, if I don't want to do anything if person is None, why could my one-liner scenario 3 be bad?

Comment: I never said it was bad, but if you're ok with your solutions , why ask a question initially ? I thought you were looking for alternatives. But if it Works for you then go for it.

Comment: But not doing anything if the object is inexistent won't give any feedback to the user on what happened.

Comment: I asked "Why could it be bad?". Not "Why is it bad". Nor I accused you of claiming it's bad. I'm just trying to understand pros and cons of all possible solutions.

Comment: Well as I said, a con of your scenario 3 is a bit like my scenario 1. You're iterating on every objects of the queryset, therefore, you can't assign only one object to `person` if emails are duplicates. Technically, the last item of the queryset will be assign to `person`, but I don't see why you want to do that.  My scenario 2 will take the first one which makes more sense in my opinion.

Comment: I already said i like the solution using the `first`. The reason that I could prefer my scenario3, is when I don't want to do anything in case there is no person with that email. In that case, using the `first`, I should then use `if person is not None`. In contrast, the `for` solution needs no further conditional code. I say again that could be better only if I want to ignore cases where object does not exist.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right! But this is why there exists plenty of solutions. It always depends on what are your needs, The `first` solution seems more appropriate for the particular example above, your scenario 3 could be better for other cases yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_object_or_404` instead, doing something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

person = get_object_or_404(Person, email="xx@xxx.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a special shortcut - [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

Equivalent of:

```
from django.http import Http404

def my_view(request):
    try:
        my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("No MyModel matches the given query.")
```

Why it's better? If you have not found an object then 404 is an appoproate answer. This shortcut allows you to keep code cleaner.