# Django OneToOne Error

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

Assume the class:

```
class M(models.Model):
      rel = models.OneToOneField(X,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now if I want to access an instance M through instance x of X I would write:

```
x=X.objects.all().first()
x.m
```

However, when there doesn't exist an instance of M related to x, it throws an error.
How do I make it return None instead of an error.

Edit:
This is related to OneToOneField, not to filtering in general

Comment: you meant `OneToOneField()`? is it just a typo? what's the error?

Comment: Not, this is the intended behavior, although there have been several people asking for this. Right now the idea is to `try`-`except` it.

Comment: Try `getattr(x, 'm', None)`.

Comment: See for example here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10227

Comment: @neverwalkaloner: I think this only catches `AttributeError`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think so also, but not sure:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Best way to retrieve object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191251/django-best-way-to-retrieve-object) I'm not sure if it's the same problem but you can look at one of my answer here. _Note the first solution in my answer._

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've just tested `getattr` with python3.5 and it works.

Comment: It's not the same as this is related to reverse OneToOneField and the other to Filtering

Answer (score 3):

There have been several people asking for this. See for example [**ticket #10227**](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10227). But I have the idea that this will not change (very) soon (if at all). A lot of code has been written with the assumption that if no reverse object is present, there will be an error, and simply changing that behavior could break several Django parts, plugins, webservers, etc.

As a result I think it is probably better to "*learn to live with it*" (at least for now). There is however something we can do to ease the pain a bit, and that is using a "*protected*" `related_name`:

```
class M(models.Model):
      rel = models.OneToOneField(X, related_name='_m', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

We can then **add a `@property`** to the `X` model:

```
class X(models.Model):

    @property
    def m(self):
        try:
            return self._m
        except M.DoesNotExists:
            return None
```

We can use this approach if we defined the `X` model ourself, or we can use *monkey patching* to add such properties to classes that have been defined in a library, etc.

So now we can (safely) use `some_x.m`. But nevertheless, this will not solve all our troubles, since for example for filtering, etc. The above will not work.

Comment: Figured this out just before you posted it, But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @WillemVanOnsem answer, you can use as an option [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function instead of try/except:

```
getattr(x, 'm', None)
```

Comment: I would call it more like helper function as it's implementation is try catch block, returns value argument if set othervise AttributeError

Answer (score 0):

You can always use

```
hasattr(model_instance,attribute)
```

Which will return false if no attribute or true if there's attribute

In your case you can check

```
hasattr(x,m)
```

will return true if there's an m for the given X and false otherwise